# How can I destroy multiple entry widgets tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am creating a program that used entry widgets like so:

```
nameField = Entry(root, width = 20)
nameField.place(x=100, y=190)...
```

I have created multiple entry widgets, is there a way I can destroy all of the entry widgets that I have created?

Comment: Have you tried `nameField.destroy()`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yes, but I have created over fields, I was looking for a more efficient way. Such as in the canvas you can use something on the lines of `w.delete("all")` which will delete all objects on the canvas. Would there be 1 line of code I could use to delete all entry widgets?

Comment: You could store them in a `list` or `dict` instead of creating standalone references, then loop over that data structure.

Comment: s= {} ; tmp =  Entry(root, width = 20) ; tmp.place(x=100, y=190); s['nameField']= tmp ; s['nameField'].destroy()

Answer (score 3):

You can store references to each widget in a list and then iterate over the list calling the `destroy()` method on each. You could also put all of the entry widgets in a single frame. When you delete the frame, any widgets inside the frame will also be deleted.